# Typescript double arrow function with interface assignment

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, arrow-functions

I am reading the following code:

```
export interface Contact {
    contactOptions?: string[];
}

const mapToContact: (
    value: Record<string, any>
  ) => Contact = (value) => {
    return {
        ...
    }
};
```

..and I don't understand of the instruction:

```
Contact = (value)
```

What does it mean? 'Contact' is an interface, why is that expression not :

```
(value: Contact)
```

I am confused by this function declaration, can anyone help me understand? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That's part of the interface. `=> Contact` is the functions return type.

You can see it more easily this way:

```
export interface Contact {
    contactOptions?: string[];
}

type MapToContactInterface = (value: Record<string, any>) => Contact;

const mapToContact: MapToContactInterface = (value) => {
    return {

    }
};
```

It says the function `mapToContact` has a return type of `Contact`.

Formatted:

```
const mapToContact: // Variable declaration
    (value: Record<string, any>) => Contact // Variable type
    = (value) => {  // Parameter list
        return {    // Function body
                    // Function body
        }           // Function body
    };              // Function body
```

Comment: Thanks! So 'Contact = (value)' works both as a type definition for the previous function (on the left) and as a parameter for the next function(on the right).. correct?

Comment: Not really. The `=> Contact` part ends the type definition. `= (value)` starts the type implementation.

Comment: But isn't the type implementation then the parameter for the next function? Isn't it (value) a parameter?

Comment: `(value)` is a parameter (list) of a function, yes. Edited the answer with an example of how you can format the function to better understand it.